# Eating food during the 9 days that's been cooked with meat

Tags: halacha, food, meat, nine-days

Is one allowed, during the nine days, to eat pareve food that was cooked with meat equipment? What about if the food was fried in oil that was used to fry chicken?
*Example:* I fried French Fries in oil that was used to make shnitzel. Would I be allowed to eat the French Fries during the 9 days?

**Note:** Not talking about scenarios where one would be allowed to eat meat [e.g. Shabbos, Seudas Mitzvah, etc.]

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17879/759

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form [kashrut.com](http://www.kashrut.com/articles/ninedays/) (Footnotes in that article point to other references:)

> All meat and poultry and their derivatives, even if no meat or poultry
>   is actually visible, e.g., chicken soup, are included. Pareve dishes
>   cooked in a utensil used for meat are permitted. [If a small piece of
>   meat accidentally fell into a pareve dish and its taste will not be
>   sensed, the dish may be eaten.]

Based on my understanding - the answer to your 1st question, about utensils is "yes", you can eat it.

While the 2nd question is not addressed, directly, it seems that since the oil is fleishig, the french fries are fleishig too, which MAY categorize in what is said in the 1st sentence regarding the chicken soup. There, even though there is no visible chicken, since a meat product, "fleishig" ingredient was used to make this soup, the soup is fleishig. So too, the fleishig oil was used to cook the french fries, and the french fries, even not having any meat itself, are considered fleishig. Again, my reasoning on this. Ask a good Rav about this. I'm curious, too.

Comment: There is definitely chicken fat in the oil after frying and it adds flavor.

Comment: What are the sources that kashrut.com cites? What exactly is the language used by their sources? Do the sources says בשר or do they use a term that connotes even food that was cooked in something that contains/contained בשר?

Comment: @MNT You can click on the link and read for yourself.