# Parameters of the meat prohibition during the nine days

Tags: minhag, meat, nine-days

In SA OC 551 the minhag of not eating *basar* during the nine days is brought down. The term basar usually refers to meat or chicken but not to all *fleishige* products (considered *fleishig* halachically). So my question is, are we dealing here with a prohibition on meat and chicken *only*, as they are considered to be a delight (for example on Yom tov one should eat **meat** since it brings שמחה) or are all *fleishige* foods included this prohibition? For example would i be able to eat liver during the nine days?

Comment: Is liver not a delight? Personally I find it offal, but others definitely think it's a treat

Comment: Notably the Minhag now need not be what it was when the Rama recorded it, so a Diyuk there is of limited value. In general people don't seem to be able to handle different kinds of meat statuses and treat all meat the same, for better or worse

Comment: Why should liver not be meat?

Comment: @DoubleAA you mean "Awful" not "offal".

Comment: Do you think you are not yotzeh meat on y.t. when eating liver?

Comment: @user6591 most probably not!

Comment: @bach liver is indeed offal

Comment: Possible dupe: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17879/8775.

Comment: Someone told me that chicken is not a delight (שמחה)--for example the mitzvah of eating basar on yom tov does not include chicken--but is still prohibited during the nine days, so obviously were not dealing with שמחת בשר per se, but all kinds of fleishigs.

Comment: Parve items cokked in a fleishig pot are permitted. I'm not sure about true fleishig items where the flieshig is a minority, for example, chulent where meat is the minority, or a slice of kishke or meat gravy. I think all these items are still prohibited.